# GLCanvas inside JPanel doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jogl, glcanvas

I am trying to add a GLCanvas with OpenGL-Content to a JPanel. The JPanel is inside a JTabbedPane. But when the GLCanvas is inside the JPanel, the Panel is just grey. When I add the GLCanvas directly into the TabbedPane, everything works fine.

[image: xxx]

Here the working code:

```
    JTabbedPane mainPane = frame.getMainPane();
    GLCanvas canvas = cogl.getCanvas();
    mainPane.add("OGL",canvas);
```

An here is the not-working code:

```
    JTabbedPane mainPane = frame.getMainPane();
    GLCanvas canvas = cogl.getCanvas();

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(canvas);

    mainPane.add("OGL",panel);
```

So how can i get the GLCanvas working inside the JPanel?

Comment: This isn't actually surprising.  `GLCanvas` is based directly off `java.awt.Canvas`.  Mixing heavy weight containers within light containers always results in weird issues, mostly relating to the z-ordering of the components (AWT components have no concept of z-ordering). While I know that was "suppose" to be fixed in Java 6, I've witnessed to many "weird" issues around it to consider using it.  Best bet, don't mix heavy and lightweight components

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems problem with `LayoutManager`, `JPanel` use `FlowLayout` as default change it to `BorderLayout` like next:

```
 JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
```

Comment: Actually, it was a Swing problem, JOGL wasn't "guilty". Good job alex2410.